# Mappings can not be assigned to error

Tags: erc-20, contract-debugging

I am trying to create a dividend function for my token. This is in the first part of the contract for my coin:

```
mapping (address => uint256) private _SavedDividend;
```

Here is the constructor code:

```
constructor() public payable ERC20Detailed(tokenName, tokenSymbol, tokenDecimals) {
  _mint(msg.sender, _totalSupply);
  _SavedDividend = 0;
}
```

Here is my view and withdraw dividend function:

```
function ViewDividend(address staker) public view returns (uint256) {
require(msg.sender != (address(0)));

  _SavedDividend = _balances[this].div(_totalSupply).mul(_balances[msg.sender]);
  return _SavedDividend;
}  

function WithdrawDividend() public {

  emit Transfer(address(this), msg.sender, _SavedDividend[msg.sender]);
  _balances[this] = _balances[this].sub(_SavedDividend[msg.sender]);
  _SavedDividend[msg.sender] = 0;
}
```

I get a multitude of errors with these including:

> TypeError: Mappings cannot be assigned to.
>       _SavedDividend = 0;
>
> TypeError: Type int_const 0 is not implicitly convertible to expected type mapping(address => uint256).
>       _SavedDividend = 0;
>
> TypeError: Mappings cannot be assigned to.
>       _SavedDividend = _balances[this].div(_totalSupply).mul(_balances[msg.sender]);
>
> TypeError: Type contract Miasma is not implicitly convertible to expected type address.
>       _SavedDividend = _balances[this].div(_totalSupply).mul(_balances[msg.sender]);
>
> TypeError: Type uint256 is not implicitly convertible to expected type mapping(address => uint256).
>       _SavedDividend = _balances[this].div(_totalSupply).mul(_balances[msg.sender]);
>
> TypeError: Return argument type mapping(address => uint256) is not implicitly convertible to expected type (type of first return variable) uint256.
>       return _SavedDividend;

I don't understand what these mean. How do I fix this?

Comment: Maybe you meant to use `_SavedDividend[msg.sender]` in those places? The code you've written doesn't really make sense, so this is just a guess as to what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You assigned a Type of `mapping` to `_SavedDividend` here:

`mapping (address => uint256) private _SavedDividend;`

... then you are trying to assign numbers to the mapping, starting here:

`_SavedDividend = 0;`

`mapping` is an indexed type similar to arrays. You need to specify *which one*. Other parts of the code imply that this is understood. Here, for example, it is the `_SavedDividend` of the `msg.sender`, so that is acceptable.

`_SavedDividend[msg.sender] = 0;`

In the lines causing trouble, it's not clear what you are trying to do. You cannot assign a simple number or return an entire mapping. You have to assign/read/return `_SavedDividend[key]`. There is a lot going on there. Token contracts and dividends, in particular, are not good practice projects.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears to be implementing ERC20, my recommendation is to inherit from the OpenZeppelin implementation, and use the internal functions to create the functionality that you require.

I suggest you look at the OpenZeppelin documentation on ERC20 tokens
https://docs.openzeppelin.org/v2.3.0/tokens#erc20

Your token can inherit from [ERC20](https://docs.openzeppelin.org/v2.3.0/api/token/erc20) and [ERC20Detailed](https://docs.openzeppelin.org/v2.3.0/api/token/erc20#erc20detailed).

It could also be worth sharing what you are trying to achieve with the dividend.

As per Rob's answer, the use of mapping is incorrect in places.  A good place to start is looking at the Solidity documentation.
https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/types.html#mapping-types

For questions on OpenZeppelin you can also ask in the [community forum](https://forum.zeppelin.solutions/)